# Does a monotone function exist such that there is a "simple" closed form for itself as well as its inverse?

Tags: closed-form, monotone-functions

Let $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ be a strictly increasing such that
$$f(-1)=-1,\quad\quad f(1)=1,\quad\quad f'(-1)=f'(1)=0$$

Letting $f$ be the cubic function uniquely characterized by these conditions, I don't think the inverse can be expressed without trigonometry or complex arithmetic:

$$2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \sin ^{-1}(y)\right)=-\frac{i \left(-1+\left(\sqrt{1-y^2}+i y\right)^{2/3}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{1-y^2}+i y}}$$

Is there any alternative which (as well as its inverse) has a closed form consisting of only non-complex addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and powers (preferably only square-root and integer powers)?

Comment: If you allow cases, then how about two quarter circles (i.e. 2nd quadrant of unit circle shifted one to the right and 4th quadrant shifted one to the left)? The inverse consists of other shifts of those quadrants and the formulas are just square roots of quadratics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ned's suggestion gave me the inspiration to realize this simple solution:
$\ x\mapsto x\sqrt{2-x^2}\ $ with the simple inverse $\ y\mapsto\sqrt{\frac{1+y}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{2}}$