# unclamped smoothstep with.... not sure if this is the right term, but "dynamic steepness"?

Tags: functions, interpolation

So, I need a smoothstep function for my game, and this seems to be the standard function that most people use:

$y = (x^2) *(3-2*x)$

This is computationally friendly, which is important, but it doesn't provide a lot of control over the curve as far as I can tell.  The advice I've received is to use the function again on it's own output to get a steeper curve, but that doesn't really allow for very fine control, nor does it allow for a more shallow curve. Also, going beyond 1 actually inverts the direction with this function.

Is there some way to control the steepness of this curve through a "strength", and continue past 0 & 1 at least a little bit.  Ideally I think I want a function that can produce graphs with a shape like these:
[Example graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DlJO.png)

This shows the kind of function I am trying to get with three different "strength" values resulting in different steepness of the drop-off.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get a function like that(I actually had to draw the graph in an image editor...).

I tried fiddling with tangents because I thought a sigmoid might at least give me easy control over the strength, but it needs to pass through the points {(0,0),(0.5,0.5),(1,1)} to be useful for interpolation and sigmoids never seem to actually reach the edge clamp values {(0,0),(1,1)} which isn't really usefull for interpolation from 0...1, or at least I haven't figured out how to do it...

Also, full disclaimer, I'm a computer scientist, not a mathematician, so please explain it to me like I'm an idiot.

Hopefully I've explained my problem adequately...  If you have questions I can try to answer them...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $1<h\leq3$ and $0<j\leq4$, and say your independent variable is $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Let $t(x)=\text{abs}(2x-1)^{\,\large j}$.

Then the function
$f(x)=0.5(1+\text{sgn}(2 x-1) \sqrt[\huge j]{\dfrac{(h-2) t(x)^3+h\ t(x)}{(2 h-3)\ t(x)^2\,+\,1}})$
does what you need with much flexibility.

Geogebra applet: https://ggbm.at/wxahvwky

Comment: Can you explain a bit about how you got this solution? I'm trying to find the inverse of this function

Comment: @positlabs I had seen the $f(x^j)^{1/j}$ kinda shape parameter somewhere else so I experimented to find a way to use it for this question. You might be interested in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647591

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0& x\leq 0\\ \frac{1}{2} \left(\tanh \left(\frac{k (2 x-1)}{2 \sqrt{(1-x) x}}\right)+1\right)& 0<x<1 \\1 & x\geq 1\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $k$ is derivative at $x=1/2$, $k>0$.

[image]

For inverse function use $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(1-2 x)}{\sqrt{k^2+\tanh ^{-1}(1-2 x)^2}}\right)$